# Glyphicon instead of carousel indicators

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to replace bootstrap indicators circles with some glyphicons.
I tried to add glyphicon to carousel indicator, but not working.
http://jsfiddle.net/bn6aA/57/

HTML

```
 <div id="locations" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators glyphicon glyphicon-refresh">
                <li data-target="#locations" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#locations" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#locations" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#locations" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active ">
                    <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>

            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#locations" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#locations" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>

        </div>
```

Comment: no it's not fine, not working what iI wan't. I wan't to replace indicator circles with glyphicon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using glyphicons as carousel indicators is not such easy thing to do because we must do some modifications.
I removed the class `carousel-indicators` from the list, i put the glyphicons inside the `custom-list` list items, and used my `custom-list` class to style the glyphicons.
Also i removed the imported `bootstrap-combined` library because it was messing up the `left` and `right` carousel controls.

The above approach has one negative side which is we cannot style the glyphicon coresponding to the current `active` slide because we removed the `carousel-indicators` class from the list.

```css
.custom-list li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
.custom-list li:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.item img {
  width: 100%;
}
.custom-list {
  top: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="locations" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="custom-list">
    <li data-target="#locations" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span>
    </li>
    <li data-target="#locations" data-slide-to="1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </li>
    <li data-target="#locations" data-slide-to="2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
    </li>
    <li data-target="#locations" data-slide-to="3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active ">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x200?text=First slide" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x200?text=Second slide" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x200?text=Third slide" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x200?text=Fourth slide" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#locations" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#locations" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know where can I find hexagon icon free?
Thank you

Comment: I think there is not hexagon glyphicon, if you need non glyphicon icons try [here](http://www.flaticon.com/search/hexagon)

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the bootstrap website (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel):

```
<!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
```

However, something is going a little wonky here, so remove the circles like this with CSS

```
.carousel-control {
    background: none !important;
    border: none;
}
```

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/bn6aA/65/

As you can see, this is still not rendering exactly correct. Some things are out of place and sized too big etc... This is because you are using bootstrap-combined.min.css V2.3.1 and bootstrap.css V3.0.0

Removing bootstrap-combined.min.css results in a much better looking solution: http://jsfiddle.net/bn6aA/64/